# Who was Sukracharya?

Tags: asuras, shukracharya

Sukracharya was a teacher of King Bali, and also of Ravana.

- Did both Bali and Ravana belong to the same Treta yuga?
- Who really was Sukracharya?
- Why did he support Asuras?
- When and how did he die?

Comment: I guess it is pretty well covered in Wikipedia.  However the article about [Sharmishtha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharmishtha) is to be read while reading about [Shukracharya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shukra).